# $cookies and hide element on login/logout and ui-router child states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I am stuck at hiding and showing the login and logout buttons at the navbar. I am setting some cookies at LoginCtrl which belongs to login.html. When user logged in I am assigning rootscope to some variables which that variable assing to ngshow/hide in  And getting those cookies in HomeCtrl. What i want to achieve is when I click log in button in the login.html Login element at the nav bar has to be gone and Username element has be to show.  In plunker when I add some nested states like my local and result is the same. But when i remove the nested structure and add simple two state its start working.

**Working Case:**

```
.state('home', { 
templateUrl:'home.html', ===>stores the navbar html
controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})

.state('login', {
templateUrl:'login.html',
controller:'LoginCtrl'
})
```

**Not Working Case:**

```
.state('home', { 
templateUrl:'home.html, ===>stores the navbar html
controller: 'HomeCtrl'})

.state('home.login', {
templateUrl:'home.login.html',
controller:'LoginCtrl'})
```

Here is plunker when you logged in login button is in place but when you rerun the app Login button is gone.
http://plnkr.co/edit/tZuvyrAUD0yCN8a3K5lF

Answer (score 0):

You problem was that you put 'some' key but get 'Some'. Here is your example: plnkr.co/edit/ZsT52SYFeRVCXpGYTMqK?p=preview

Comment: @Errorpo Its correct in my local. I just simplified my local. So you corrected it and when you logged in `Login` element is gone or still in place?

Comment: It works when i refresh page. The problem that your homeCtrl is called once when app start. It doens' watch after any variable. It means when you change cookie your HomeCtrl doensn't know about it. You need watch after smth. Or change rootScope.

Comment: @Errorpo Why did you comment out the auth part? What is the point of that?

Comment: I just wanted you know that that rootScope works as well. And if you want to use cookie you need follow other way.